# How do I Parameterize a null string with DBNull.Value clearly and quickly

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, naming-conventions

I got tired of writing the following code:

```
/* Commenting out irrelevant parts
public string MiddleName;
public void Save(){
    SqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
    // blah blah...boring INSERT statement with params etc go here. */
    if(MiddleName==null){
        myCmd.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", DBNull.Value);
    }
    else{
        myCmd.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", MiddleName);
    }
    /*
    // more boring code to save to DB.
}*/
```

So, I wrote this:

```
public static object DBNullValueorStringIfNotNull(string value)
{
    object o;
    if (value == null)
    {
        o = DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        o = value;
    }
    return o;
}

// which would be called like:
myCmd.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", DBNullValueorStringIfNotNull(MiddleName));
```

**If this is a good way to go about doing this then what would you suggest as the method name? *DBNullValueorStringIfNotNull* is a bit verbose and confusing.**

I'm also open to ways to alleviate this problem entirely. I'd LOVE to do this:

```
myCmd.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", MiddleName==null ? DBNull.Value : MiddleName);
```

but that won't work because the "Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string and 'System.DBNull'".

I've got C# 3.5 and SQL Server 2005 at my disposal if it matters.

Comment: I wouldn't write the null instance at all - if the value is null, omit from the insert statement.

Comment: but that won't work. - please be specific, why people should guess?

Comment: @Andrey: His statement won't compile (the compiler will say there is no implicit conversion between `DBNull` and `string`).

Comment: @OMG: That's nice in theory, but it's pretty rare to find people who will write different insert statements depending upon whether or not particular parameters are null. It adds a lot of maintenance overhead with little or no practical benefit (other than being able to take advantage of column default values, of course).

Comment: @Andrey: because the "Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string and 'System.DBNull'"

Comment: @OMG. People dynamically create their insert statements based on if the input is null? Man, i'm lazy.

Comment: @Adam, passing DBNull.Value as a parameter will let the column  default values do there thing regardless.

Comment: Less to transfer over the wire == faster.

Comment: @OMG, how much faster could it possible be (seriously, I'm not familiar with how .net and SQL Server communicate)? With TCP I know most of the time would be spend in RTT for such small data packets.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Cast either of your values to `object` and it will compile.

```
myCmd.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", MiddleName==null ? (object)DBNull.Value : MiddleName);
```

Comment: Sweet: `MiddleName ?? (object)DBNull.Value` works! Or better yet `public static readonly object DBNullValue = (object)DBNull.Value;` with `MiddleName ?? DBNullValue`! You are my hero.

Comment: Argh, i have to wait 3 more minutes before I can accept your answer.

Comment: @David: Nice! Hadn't even considered coalescing. I'll have to start doing that in my code. I thought about caching the value as you describe, but wanted to keep the code to one line.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch: Rather than `MiddleName==null ? (object)DBNull.Value : MiddleName`, you can also use `MiddleName ?? SqlString.Null;` ([Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlstring.null.aspx)).  This might not work on some databases.

Answer (score 26):

You can avoid the explicit cast to `object` using `SqlString.Null` instead of `DBNull.Value`:

```
MiddleName ?? SqlString.Null
```

There are corresponding types for int, datetime, and so forth. Here's a code snippet with a couple more examples:

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", StartDate ?? SqlDateTime.Null);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", EndDate ?? SqlDateTime.Null);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", Month ?? SqlInt16.Null);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormatID", FormatID ?? SqlInt32.Null);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email ?? SqlString.Null);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZIP", ZIP ?? SqlBoolean.Null);
```

Answer (score 12):

Personally this is what I would do with an extension method (make sure this goes into a static class)

```
public static object GetStringOrDBNull(this string obj)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj) ? DBNull.Value : (object) obj
}
```

Then you'd have

```
myCmd.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", MiddleName.GetStringOrDBNull());
```

Comment: I do like the name. So +1 for that. I like the accepted answer's solution better though. :-)

Comment: See if you change your mind after instead of having 100 if statements you have 100 ternary operators.

Comment: I'm actually using a null coalescing operator. You have to agree that `MiddleName ?? DBNullValue` is pretty darn easy. But +1 for your comment too.

Comment: +1 but I would prefer to use `DBNull.Value` only for actual `null` values and leave empty strings as is.  I use `return (object) obj ?? DBNull.Value;` in my version of your extension method.

Comment: I have a lot of "such" parameters and extension method is the way to go in this case. Thanks!

Comment: What's about another types Nullables like int?, decimal?, Datetime?, byte[], short?, etc ? Any full sample about it ?

Comment: Since you would also do the same for other types, as @Kiquenet points out, I'd personally go for a common method name for all, eg. GetValueOrDbNull(). Makes typing easier, search/replace easier, and indicates they all do the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

```
myCmd.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", MiddleName ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

@David Thanks for your suggestion. The following method works great!

```
MiddleName ?? (object)DBNull.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, we'd all love to do `myCmd.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", MiddleName ?? DBNull.Value);`. Or better still, have the freakin' SqlClient layer understand that CLR `null` should be mapped to `DBNull.Value` when adding a parameter. Unfortunately the .Net type system closes the first alternative, and the implementation of SqlClient closes the second.

I'd go with a well known function name, like [Coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) or [IsNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx). Any DB developer will recognize what they do in an instant, from the name alone.

Comment: There are good reasons that `null` doesn't map to `DBNull.Value`. Namely that it forces you to assign a value to every parameter, even if that "value" is a database null value.

Comment: Furthermore, having the ability to do string ?? DBNull.Value might be nice for this particular circumstance, you have to consider the issue from a compiler perspective: What is the return type of that expression? Should the compiler look for the most common ancestor, even if it's `object`?

Comment: Perhaps I wans't clear what I mean by 'the CLR type system': the impossibility to establish the compile time type of the expression `(type1 ?? type2)`. We're saying the same thing.

Comment: I love how you still have a Pony for your avatar.

Comment: @David: Yea, I grabbed it and made it persistent :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather give you two totally different suggestions:

1. Use an ORM. There are plenty of non-intrusive ORM tools.
2. Write your own wrapper for building commands, with a cleaner interface. Something like:

   ```
   public class MyCommandRunner {
     private SqlCommand cmd;

     public MyCommandRunner(string commandText) {
       cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText);
     }

     public void AddParameter(string name, string value) {
       if (value == null)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(name, DBNull.Value);
       else
         cmd.Parameters.Add(name, value);
     }

     // ... more AddParameter overloads
   }
   ```

If you rename your `AddParameter` methods to just `Add`, you can use it in a very slick way:

```
var cmd = new MyCommand("INSERT ...")
  {
    { "@Param1", null },
    { "@Param2", p2 }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using nullable properties instead of public fields and an 'AddParameter' method (don't know if this code is optimized or correct, just off the top of my head):

```
private string m_MiddleName;

public string MiddleName
{
  get { return m_MiddleName; }
  set { m_MiddleName = value; }
}

.
.
.

public static void AddParameter(SQLCommand cmd, string parameterName, SQLDataType dataType, object value)
{
  SQLParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterName, dataType);

  if (value is string) { // include other non-nullable datatypes
    if (value == null) {
      param.value = DBNull.Value;
    } else {
      param.value = value;
    }
  } else { 

    // nullable data types
    // UPDATE: HasValue is for nullable, not object type
    if (value.HasValue) // {{{=====================================================
    {
          param.value = value;
    } else 
    {
          param.value = DBNull.Value;
    }
  }
}

.
.
.
AddParameter(cmd, "@MiddleName", SqlDbType.VarChar, MiddleName);
```

Comment: value.HasValue not compiles: HasValue is for nullable<T>, not object type