# Is there a more elegant form for assigning NULL to InsertCommand's NVarChar?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-insert, sqldataadapter

This code works for me very well:

```
if (someStr == null)
  da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@SOMESTR", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
else
  da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@SOMESTR", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = someStr;
```

But my intuition tells me that there may be a one-liner version of it. Something like:

```
  da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@SOMESTR", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = someStr==null ? DBNull.Value : someStr ;
```

But the one-liner I just posted above fails of course because `DBNull.Value` doesn't cast to String.

Is there a way to accomplish the one liner I so desire?

Comment: You could cast someStr to an object

Comment: @cadrell0 Your approach works! Please post as answer so that I can accept.

Comment: We've done this in the past with casting: (object)DBNull.Value should do it for you. (or similarly close syntax)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Parameterize a null string with DBNull.Value clearly and quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602949/how-do-i-parameterize-a-null-string-with-dbnull-value-clearly-and-quickly)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could cast someStr to an object

For example:

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@SOMESTR", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = someStr==null ? DBNull.Value : (object)someStr;
```

Or you could do as Oded and Servy suggested and use an extension method.  While it may add a few lines of code it will save you from duplicate code.

As Servy pointed out, putting it on `object` could lead to clutter.  For this reason I would put it on `SqlParameter`

```
public static void SetValue(this SqlParameter parameter, object value)
{
    parameter.Value = value == null ? DBNull.Value : value;
}
```

Then use it like so

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@SOMESTR", SqlDbType.NVarChar).SetValue(someStr);
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a function or extension method that will do the test and make the assignments as needed. Pass in `someStr` and the parameter name.

You will then be able to set the parameter in one line.

Comment: That's elegant but defeats the purpose of reducing the number of lines of code.

Comment: @scatmoi - Why is that goal so desirable? And if you factor out such a function properly, it can be reused for many parameters, reducing the overall LOC.

Comment: @scatmoi - Well, the first objection for MS to include it is that it is easy enough to implement by yourself. They can't foresee _every_ possible requirement someone _may_ have - can you imagine what the size of the framework libraries would be if they would **not** stop _somewhere_?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following extension method (or make it a non-extension method if you prefer)

```
public static object ConvertNull(this object obj)
{
    return obj ?? DBNull.Value;
}
```

You can then do:

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@SOMESTR", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = someStr.ConvertNull()
```

Comment: That's beautiful. But moves the extra lines of code from one place to another. I wish ConvertNull() were a C# library function.

Comment: @scatmoi If you only ever do this once, it increases the lines of code.  If you do it more than once it decreases it.  If you happen to only ever do this once then just don't make the method (but I doubt that's the case).

Comment: +1 It makes 1-2 extra lines in an extension method class, which you can take advantage of over and over. I like this better than my previous implementations.

Comment: Note that you'll want this in an extensions class that you only include in contexts where you deal with DB commands a lot; adding extra "clutter" to the intellisense for `object` by putting this in a general purpose extensions would likely do more harm than good..

Comment: @Servy et al you are of course right, but then it raises the question: How come Microsoft didn't provide this as a library method in any of its VS versions?

Comment: @scatmoi Well, for starters, it's so easy for you to make there's no reason you *need* them to do it for you.  Next, as with any other feature, it doesn't exist because it wasn't: 1) thought of 2) selected for development 2) coded 3) tested 4) deployed.  My guess is that this one stopped before #1, and if not there, then #2.  Language features do no "exists by default unless there is a reason to exclude them".  Features are, by default, not implemented, until all of the required steps are completed to implement them.

Comment: @Servy +1 for a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@SOMESTR", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ((object)someStr) ?? DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a stored procedure for inserting, set default value for your argument as null, Use that stored procedure for your insert command, then don't just pass that argument to that sproc..