# How to pass DBNull in Nvarchar type(procedure paramter) in MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, nvarchar, dbnull

I'm using `MySQL` `c# 4`

My Procedure parameter is `NVARCHAR(100)`.

So what I'm doing is

```
MySqlParameter DBParam1 = new MySqlParameter("var_Name", (object)(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)? DBNull.Value : Name));

MySqlCommand _DBCommand = new MySqlCommand();
_DBCommand.Connection = _DBConnection;
_DBCommand.CommandText = "udsp_ProcedureName";
_DBCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
_DBCommand.Parameters.Clear();
_DBCommand.Parameters.Add(DBParam1);
```

so this is throwing **"ErrorMessage":"Unhandled type encountered"**

How can i solve this?

what i looked into

[How do I Parameterize a null string with DBNull.Value clearly and quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602949/how-do-i-parameterize-a-null-string-with-dbnull-value-clearly-and-quickly)

[Is there a more elegant form for assigning NULL to InsertCommand's NVarChar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981012/is-there-a-more-elegant-form-for-assigning-null-to-insertcommands-nvarchar)

[Exception when AddWithValue parameter is NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451085/exception-when-addwithvalue-parameter-is-null)

Comment: `new MySqlParameter("@var_Name"` , notice `@`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `DBNull.Value` to `NVARCHAR` type will throw an exception

> "ErrorMessage":"Unhandled type encountered"

So I passed this as Empty string.

```
MySqlParameter DBParam1 = new MySqlParameter("var_Name", (object)(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)? string.Empty : Name));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the constructor to set the value, while it expects a value of `MySqlDBType`.

Try this:

```
MySqlParameter DBParam1 = new MySqlParameter("@var_Name", MySqlType.VarChar)
DBParam1.Value = (object)(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) ? DBNull.Value : Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know that the nullable parameter will always be of string type then you can use the below code. Using this you don't have to replace null with with blank(string.Empty)-

```
MySqlParameter pm = new MySqlParameter();
                        pm.ParameterName= "ParamName";
                        pm.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
                        pm.IsNullable = true;
                        if(param.Value!=null)
                            pm.Value = param.Value;
                        else
                        {
                            pm.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
                        }

                        _DBCommand.Parameters.Add(pm);
```

Please note that for the nullable varchar parameters you don't have to set any value at-all instead it will set "IsNullable" to "true" and need to set the "MySqlDbType" to "VarChar". For all not null values it will set the value and no need to set type explicitly. This code is working for me , hope it will help.