# How to capture a null Parameter and allow Parsing with DBNull in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, database, parsing, parameters, ado.net

So I am passing these 18 parameters to my DAL and then inserting or updating my Access database.

I have 2 fields that are `DateTime` and one that is and `int`. Both DateTime and the int parameters are 'not required', which means that can be empty strings.

I've have a problem when I pass my `txtBirthDate.Text, txtHireDate.Text, and txtReportsTo.Text` that if they have been left null, my DAL screams at me with a `FormatException` that can't get past parsing a null element.

So my problem right now is, I'm unsure where to Parse the `DateTime` and `int` variable to allow my Parameters to accept them. I am also unsure how to set these variables to `DBNull.Value` that are have been past through to my DAL as empty strings.

Here is a sample of my DAL method call:

```
rowsAdded = ((DataAccessLayer)Application["dbAccess"]).insertEmployees(txtLname.Text, txtFname.Text, txtTitle.Text, 
         txtCourt.Text,txtBday.Text,txtHireDate.Text, txtAddress.Text, txtCity.Text,txtRegion.Text,txtPostalCode.Text,
         txtCountry.Text, txtHomePhone.Text, txtExtension.Text, upPhoto.FileName.ToString(),txtNotes.Text,txtReports.Text,txtPassword.Text);
```

Here is my DAL method:

```
 public int insertEmployees(string lname, string fname, string title, string toc, string birth, string hire, string address, string city,
    string region,string postal,string country, string phone, string ext,string photo, string notes, string report, string pass)
{
    string last = lname;
    string first = fname;
    string tlt = title;
    string tOfc = toc;
    string addy = address;
    string town = city;
    string reg = country;
    string phum = phone;
    string exten = ext;
    string rep = report;// THIS IS Int
    string pas = pass;
    string pc = postal;
    string note = notes;
    string regions = region;
    string hD = hire;// THIS IS DATETIME
    string bD = birth;// THIS IS DATETIME
    string pho = photo;
    int rows = 0;
        dbString = "INSERT INTO [Employees] ([LastName],[FirstName],[Title],[TitleOfCourtesy],[BirthDate],[HireDate],[Address],[City],[Region],[PostalCode]," +
        "[Country],[HomePhone],[Extension],[Photo],[Notes],[ReportsTo],[Password]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        string queryLast = "Select @@Identity";

        conn.Open();
        oleCommand = new OleDbCommand(dbString, conn);

        oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@LastName", OleDbType.VarChar, 20, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 10, 0, "LastName", DataRowVersion.Original, null)).Value = last;
        oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 10, 0, "FirstName", DataRowVersion.Original, null)).Value = first;
        oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Title", OleDbType.VarChar, 30, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 10, 0, "Title", DataRowVersion.Original, null)).Value = tlt ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
        oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@TitleOfCourtesy", OleDbType.VarChar, 25, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 10, 0, "TitleOfCourtesy", DataRowVersion.Original, null)).Value = tOfc ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
//DATE  oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@BirthDate", OleDbType.DBDate, 20, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 10, 0, "BirthDate", DataRowVersion.Original, null)).Value = (object)bD ?? DBNull.Value;
//DATE  oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@HireDate", OleDbType.DBDate, 20, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 10, 0, "HireDate", DataRowVersion.Original, null)).Value = (object)hD ?? DBNull.Value;
        oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar, 60, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 10, 0, "Address", DataRowVersion.Original, null)).Value = addy ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
        oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@City", OleDbType.VarChar, 15, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 10, 10, "City", DataRowVersion.Original, null)).Value = phum ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
        oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Region", OleDbType.VarChar, 15, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 10, 0, "Region", DataRowVersion.Original, null)).Value = regions ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
        oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@PostalCode", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 10, 0, "PostalCode", DataRowVersion.Original, null)).Value = pc ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
        oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Country", OleDbType.VarChar, 15, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 10, 0, "Country", DataRowVersion.Original, null)).Value = reg ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
        oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@HomePhone", OleDbType.VarChar, 24, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 10, 0, "HomePhone", DataRowVersion.Original, null)).Value = phum ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
        oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Extension", OleDbType.VarChar, 4, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 10, 0, "Extension", DataRowVersion.Original, null)).Value = exten ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
        oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Photo", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 10, 0, "Photo", DataRowVersion.Original, null)).Value = pho ?? (object)DBNull.Value; ;
        oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Notes", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 10, 0, "Notes", DataRowVersion.Original, null)).Value = note ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
  //INT oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ReportsTo", OleDbType.Integer, 2, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 10, 0, "ReportsTo", DataRowVersion.Original, null)).Value = (object)rep ?? DBNull.Value;
        oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 10, 0, "Password", DataRowVersion.Original, null)).Value = pas ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
        rows = (int)oleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        oleCommand.CommandText = queryLast;
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Parameterize a null string with DBNull.Value clearly and quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602949/how-do-i-parameterize-a-null-string-with-dbnull-value-clearly-and-quickly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for string values you can use this expression:

```
oleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@LastName", OleDbType.VarChar, 20, 
                                             ParameterDirection.Input, false, 10, 
                                             0, "LastName", 
                                             DataRowVersion.Original, null)
                         ).Value = String.IsNullOrEmpty(last) ? DBNull.Value : last;
```

Repeat it for the rest of string values