# Exception about data type

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview

I've created an application where there is a datagridview. When I click on a button, the data written in the datagridview are sent to my database in a table. But I have an exception and I'm lost.

> The error :System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : 'Fail to convert nvarchar value 'B003382A3'  to int value.'

I don't even know why he tries to convert into int because my data is nvarchar in my DB. The only suggestion I would have is that he is inverting cells.

**My code:**

```
private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");
    maConnexion.Open();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if ((row.Cells[20].Value != null) && (bool)row.Cells[20].Value)
        {
            SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();

            command = new SqlCommand("update FailAndPass set Machine=@machine, ProgCode=@pc, BoardName=@BName, BoardNumber=@BNumber, Tester=@T, DateTest=@DT, TimeTest=@TT, TimeStart=@TS, FComponent=@FC, Message=@Mess, TotalTestProg=@TTP, ReadValue=@RV, ValueReference=@VR, PTolerance=@PT, FaultCodeByOP=@FCBO, FaultDetail=@FD,  RepairingDate=@RD, RepairingTime = @RT, ReportingOperator=@RO WHERE SerialNum=@Serial", maConnexion);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial", textBox1.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", row.Cells[0].Value != null ? row.Cells[0].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pc", row.Cells[2].Value != null ? row.Cells[2].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BName", row.Cells[3].Value != null ? row.Cells[3].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BNumber", row.Cells[4].Value != null ? row.Cells[4].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T", row.Cells[5].Value != null ? row.Cells[5].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DT", row.Cells[6].Value != null ? row.Cells[6].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", row.Cells[7].Value != null ? row.Cells[7].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TS", row.Cells[8].Value != null ? row.Cells[8].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FC", row.Cells[9].Value != null ? row.Cells[9].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mess", row.Cells[10].Value != null ? row.Cells[10].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TTP", row.Cells[11].Value != null ? row.Cells[11].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RV", row.Cells[12].Value != null ? row.Cells[12].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VR", row.Cells[13].Value != null ? row.Cells[13].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PT", row.Cells[14].Value != null ? row.Cells[14].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FCBO", row.Cells[15].Value != null ? row.Cells[15].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FD", row.Cells[16].Value != null ? row.Cells[16].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RD", row.Cells[17].Value != null ? row.Cells[17].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RT", row.Cells[18].Value != null ? row.Cells[18].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RO", row.Cells[19].Value != null ? row.Cells[19].Value : DBNull.Value);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }

    maConnexion.Close();
    this.Hide();
    Repair rep = new Repair();
    rep.Show();
}
```

Here is a pic of my DB:

[image: Pics]

---

I've used the debugger and it seems my cells aren't right. The first column in my datagridview is Machine, and the corresponding cell in the code is row.cells[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTYjL.png).

It seems that all my cells are not in the right order as they seem to be. What the hell is this? I mean, normally BoardName is the third cell, but I put row.cell[2] I don't have the error anymore. And it's not the only one cell to have this error.

Comment: All columns in the Table `FailAndPass` are of type `NVARCHAR`?

Comment: I assumed all columns except `SerialNum` are nullables. Try using `DbType` to specify data type for string parameters, e.g. `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", row.Cells[0].Value != null ? row.Cells[0].Value : DBNull.Value).DbType = DbType.String;`.

Comment: side note: `private void AddParameter(SqlCommand command, string ParameterName, object value)
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(ParameterName, value != null ? value : DBNull.Value);
        }`

Comment: @RomanoZumbé Not all the columns, like the one concern BoardName is nvarchar, but the next one to it BoardNumber is int.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto i'll try sir ! Yes they are all nullable

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto not working still have the same error

Comment: I know it is not an int haha ! And i know i can't parse. But i've never said in my code or in my database that this column is int !

Comment: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ - quote from blog post "There is a problem with the AddWithValue() function: it has to infer the database type for your query parameter. Here’s the thing: sometimes it gets it wrong."

Comment: ISNT an int !!!

Comment: You're said that `BoardName` has `NVARCHAR` data type, so that you can write like this: `command.Parameters.Add("@BName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = row.Cells[3].Value != null ? row.Cells[3].Value.ToString() : DBNull.Value`. I prefer `Add` to `AddWithValue` on this assignment.

Comment: I've used your code, i have an error saying it can't determine the type of the expression because there is no implicit conversion between "String" and "System.DBNull"

Comment: Ah, I'm slipped a little bit. How about casting `DbNull.Value` to `object` type: `command.Parameters.Add("@BName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = row.Cells[3].Value == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : row.Cells[3].Value`?

Comment: Back to error from the beginning with the nvarchar and int......

Comment: How about cast all to same object & then do ToString: `command.Parameters.Add("@BName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = (row.Cells[3].Value == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)row.Cells[3].Value).ToString()`?

Comment: Don't change anything ^^ see my update

Answer (score 1):

Update with your update:

The cell you've been selecting has a corresponding `int` value int he database. I suggest you check your `datagridview` population - as for the positions within the row to change, there must have been a change in the code.

For future reference, it's better not to deny that there is an int within the database table, when there is, as it really helps with answering the question and can provide a much simpler solution and to guide you where to look.

The rest of the answer - while helpful - is window dressing at this stage.

---

Use

```
row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() // wherever you are getting the value and it's not null.
```

And also use

```
command.Parameters.Add(.../...
```

for [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types)

```
parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@InputParm", OleDbType.VarChar, 12);  
// which explicitly types the datatype - with the number of char.
parameter.Value = "Sample Value";
```

There [can be issues](https://forums.asp.net/t/1200255.aspx?Parameters%20AddWithValue%20vs%20Parameters%20Add%20) with datatype conversions using AddWithValue.

Comment: I've tested your code upside, doesnt work still the same error. Dont think it would come from add.

Answer (score 0):

I' m always using this style of code for working with SQL

```
 SqlConnection connection = new 
 SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLConnectionString"]);

 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
 command.CommandTimeout = 1000;
 command.Connection = connection;
 command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 command.CommandText = "KULLANICI_OKU";

 SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
 parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
 parameter.ParameterName = "@KULLANICI";
 parameter.DbType = DbType.String;
 parameter.Value = user;
 command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

In my opinion working with store procedures is better way for sql.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should know: you can't assign `DBNull.Value` into a `string` (`nvarchar` in SQL) or other struct value types because they're incompatible each other. Common way to use ternary operator between `DBNull.Value` & `string` (or struct types) is casting `DBNull.Value` to `object` type.

Here is an example how to perform cast against `DBNull.Value` in ternary operator:

```
// a & b are cell numbers for respective cells
// change to any number representing the cell order

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if ((row.Cells[20].Value != null) && (bool)row.Cells[20].Value)
    {
        SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();

        command = new SqlCommand("update FailAndPass set Machine=@machine, ProgCode=@pc, BoardName=@BName, BoardNumber=@BNumber, Tester=@T, DateTest=@DT, TimeTest=@TT, TimeStart=@TS, FComponent=@FC, Message=@Mess, TotalTestProg=@TTP, ReadValue=@RV, ValueReference=@VR, PTolerance=@PT, FaultCodeByOP=@FCBO, FaultDetail=@FD,  RepairingDate=@RD, RepairingTime = @RT, ReportingOperator=@RO WHERE SerialNum=@Serial", maConnexion);
        // other parameters

        // integer value parameter example
        command.Parameters.Add("@pc", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[a].Value != null ? row.Cells[a]Value : (object)DBNull.Value;

        // string value parameter example
        command.Parameters.Add("@BName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = (row.Cells[b].Value != null ? (object)row.Cells[b].Value : (object)DBNull.Value).ToString();

        // other parameters

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
}

// other stuff
```

If the compiler supports null-coalescing operator, it's even more simpler:

```
// integer parameter
command.Parameters.Add("@pc", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[a].Value ?? (object)DBNull.Value;

// string parameter
command.Parameters.Add("@BName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = (row.Cells[b].Value ?? (object)DBNull.Value).ToString();
```

Reference:

[How do I Parameterize a null string with DBNull.Value clearly and quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602949/how-do-i-parameterize-a-null-string-with-dbnull-value-clearly-and-quickly)

Comment: When i'm using this way i have this error : System.FormatException : fail converting value string in int32.'

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i've found the solution of my problem.

Here is the code :

```
private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");
        maConnexion.Open();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {


            if ((row.Cells[20].Value != null) && (bool)row.Cells[20].Value)
            {

                SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();


                command = new SqlCommand("update FailAndPass set Machine=@machine, ProgCode=@pc, BoardName=@BName, BoardNumber=@BNumber, Tester=@T, DateTest=@DT, TimeTest=@TT, TimeStart=@TS, FComponent=@FC, Message=@Mess, TotalTestProg=@TTP, ReadValue=@RV, ValueReference=@VR, PTolerance=@PT, FaultDetail=@FD, RepairingDate=@RD, RepairingTime=@RT, ReportingOperator=@RO, FaultCodeByOP=@FCBO  WHERE SerialNum=@Serial", maConnexion);

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", row.Cells[1].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial", textBox1.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pc", row.Cells[3].Value != null ? row.Cells[3].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BName", row.Cells[4].Value != null ? row.Cells[4].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BNumber", row.Cells[5].Value != null ? row.Cells[5].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T", row.Cells[6].Value != null ? row.Cells[6].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DT", row.Cells[7].Value != null ? row.Cells[7].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", row.Cells[8].Value != null ? row.Cells[8].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TS", row.Cells[9].Value != null ? row.Cells[9].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FC", row.Cells[11].Value != null ? row.Cells[11].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mess", row.Cells[10].Value != null ? row.Cells[10].Value : DBNull.Value);                   
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TTP", row.Cells[12].Value != null ? row.Cells[12].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RV", row.Cells[13].Value != null ? row.Cells[13].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VR", row.Cells[14].Value != null ? row.Cells[14].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PT", row.Cells[15].Value != null ? row.Cells[15].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FD", row.Cells[16].Value != null ? row.Cells[16].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RD", row.Cells[17].Value != null ? row.Cells[17].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RT", row.Cells[18].Value != null ? row.Cells[18].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RO", row.Cells[19].Value != null ? row.Cells[19].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FCBO", row.Cells[20].Value != null ? row.Cells[20].Value : DBNull.Value);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();




            }
        }
```

}

Now i can replace all addwithvalue by add.

Explanation : It seems that a Cell does not being count as you would with a column or index. I though that the cell was waiting for an index [0] -> [max].
Or, i saw that row.cells[0] didn't contain the name of the machine but was NULL.
In consequences, if my cell was starting at index[0], all my data were off-set. Then, sure enough, BoardName was in the ProgCode Cell so inserted in the ProgCode column , which is int-type, in the database and so raised the error !

That was mind blowing, and i've done this step by step. But thank you everyone for your help because at least you've learned me some things !

Comment: As far as I remember, Cell[0] is the row selector.

Comment: Oh so that's explaining a lot