# How can I insert a value because all my parameters is null?

Tags: c#

```
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@updateMode", DbType.String, entCommon.UpdateMode);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@requestNumber", DbType.String, entCommon.RequestNumber);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@description", DbType.String, entCommon.Description);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@RequestTypeID", DbType.String, entCommon.RequestTypeID);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@requestPriorityID", DbType.String, entCommon.RequestPriorityID);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@remarks", DbType.String, entCommon.Remarks);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@requestedBy", DbType.String, entCommon.RequestedBy);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@requestedDate", DbType.String, entCommon.RequestedDate);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@approvedBy", DbType.String, entCommon.ApprovedBy);
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@approvedDate", DbType.String, entCommon.ApprovedDate);
dbCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
DataSet dsData = null;
dsData = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand);
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking

Comment: If all of your parameter is `NULL`, then don't insert into database simple

Comment: you need to insert NULL in database?

Comment: I cannot insert a another data because the entCommon.UpdateMode is null, what can I do?

Comment: Unclear with your ask. If you are looking to Insert null, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602949/how-do-i-parameterize-a-null-string-with-dbnull-value-clearly-and-quickly

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear!

If you want to set null value for SQL parameter - use

```
... = DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: How can I construct it in my UI here is my Code for UI;                              
  if (txtBox_RNumber.Text != "" && txtBox_Des.Text != "")
            {
                BusCommon busCommon = new BusCommon("connDBPSC");
                EntCommon entCommon = new EntCommon();
                DataTable dtInf = busCommon.InsertITRequests(entCommon);
                }